# migrating big menu to bootstrap

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm looking for migrate my [django attendance application](http://code.google.com/p/ghap/) to bootstrap UI. This application has a lot of options classifieds in a big menu:

[image: ghap menu screenshot]

I know that bootstrap supports submenus and can be a solution. But I will like to know if exists some more elegant approach.

Also, a mobile friendly solution will be wellcome.

Comment: Quick Google pulled up this which may be some help: http://codecanyon.net/item/responsive-mega-menu/full_screen_preview/3296119

Comment: @BillyMoat, reading license and digging forums it is not clear that I can distribute it into my open source solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free CSS BigMenu code is integrated with Bootstrap and here is the code/sample link:

http://www.bootply.com/g53fBbpDYE